# Access the data of variable outside the function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the value of the `pend` variable outside the variable and sending it as a response, but I am getting it as `undefined`.

```
app.post('/getData', function(req, res){               
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                var array;
                var id = "4136354161ff135631";
                var cursor =db.collection('messages').find( { "_id": ObjectId(id) } );
                cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                   assert.equal(err, null);
                   if (doc != null) {
                      pend=doc;             
                   }        
                });  

                 if(i === 5(length)){  // -----> response is sent once the loop get over
                   console.log(pend);
                   res.send(pend);
                   db.close();
                   }            
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for loop is async you are expecting pend before its getting computed , try the following:

```
app.post('/getData', function(req, res){               
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                var array;
                var id = "4136354161ff135631";
                var cursor =db.collection('messages').find( { "_id": ObjectId(id) } );
                cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                   assert.equal(err, null);
                   if (doc != null) {
                      pend=doc;             
                   }   

                   if(i === 5){ 
                   console.log(pend);
                   res.send(pend);
                   db.close();
                   }        
                });     

            }


    });
});
```

Comment: it is not sending the response and i want to send response after the for loop is over.

Comment: thanks subburaj for quick response..but i am trying your solution and the response is generated.plzz help mi if  i am going wrong anywhere

Comment: its getting struck in the if condition where res.send(); code is written

Comment: yes the problem solved the response is generated but there is database connection error.i.e after fetching 3 ids data its showing that mongodb socket is closed..needed a favour from u thanku..

Comment: yea thanku  subburaj for helping mi out ,that really helped mi a lot.thanks a lot once again

Comment: Yes it didn't work for me. Its giving can't set headers after they are sent exception.

Comment: can't set headers after they are sent exception means u r trying to send the response more than once for a single request..